# How to add a DNS record with no subdomain in Mac OS X Server?

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx-server, bind

How do I add a DNS record, through the GUI or command line, to Mac OS X Server that is simply the domain name (with no subdomain)?

For example I want to resolve `http://foo.com` to 192.168.1.100.

There is no facility in the GUI, it forces you to add a subdomain.

Comment: (Just a guess) Try the at symbol: "@", it works on Bind and I'd be surprised if there's something else behind the scenes.

Comment: The GUI throughs an error saying "Numbers, letters, hypens only". What would the zone look like on the command line? @   IN  A 192.168.1.100

Answer (score 1):

Create a zone named "foo.com.", and inside it create a machine (A) record for "foo.com." -- the trailing period on the machine name indicates that the name is "fully qualified", and that the zone name shouldn't be implicitly added.